# Reason for aquatic plant roots

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy

My question is about why aquatic plants have roots. At first they seem a bit superfluous to me because leaves of the plants could just absorb nutrients directly from the water thereby skipping a need for root function that land plants have to pull nutrients from the soil. I then wonder if nutrient trafficking is the reason for the root system as diffusion may not occur efficiently through thick leaves.

Comment: Also consider alternative uses, such as anchoring/staying in one place.

Comment: I did consider that and that makes sense but doesn't solve why roots still are the nutrient absorbing part of the plants rather than the entire plant.

Comment: According to [this](http://www.countrysideinfo.co.uk/wetland_survey/adaptns.htm) article, Bladderworts have evolved this ability.